# django-celery doesn't work with CONN_MAX_AGE

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery, django-celery

I am using Django 1.6.5, celery 3.1.13 and django-celery 3.1.10.Django has a new configuration "CONN_MAX_AGE" for database pooling since 1.6, but the problem is, when I config the database without CONN_MAX_AGE, the celery works well. But if I set CONN_MAX_AGE to any value, the celery will report (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') and won't beat.

My configuration is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 28000,  # if comment this line out, celery works well
    },
}

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERYBEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL = 60
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('library.task',)

import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Then run celery with

```
python manage.py celeryd -B -lDEBUG
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you set `CONN_MAX_AGE': 28000`, are you able to access your SQL?

Comment: @ChillarAnand yeah only celery fails

Comment: I have set `CONN_MAX_AGE` in my server & celery is working fine. Not sure what is going wrong for you. Can you post the traceback for celery?

Comment: @ChillarAnand are you using django >= 1.6.0?  the traceback is https://dpaste.de/1eLU

Comment: I am using Django==1.6.5. django-celery is causing this error. Add `CONN_MAX_AGE`, run `python manage.py migrate djcelery` & `python manage.py syncdb` & try scheduling tasks.

Comment: @ChillarAnand I figure it out -- I setup some tasks right after djcelery.setup_loader(), but, for some season, at that time point the celery is not fully started.

Comment: Fixed in celery 4.2 https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4292